# Support align attribute for HTML img tag

Tags: feature-request, images

The ability to make text flow around images would be a nice touch!

Comment: any updates on how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 8):

The `align` attribute [is deprecated](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_IMG.asp), and is not allowed at all in `http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd`, which is the DTD which sites in the Stack Overflow family use.

In that DTD, the allowed attributes for image are as follows:

```
<!ATTLIST IMG
  %attrs;                              -- %coreattrs, %i18n, %events --
  src         %URI;          #REQUIRED -- URI of image to embed --
  alt         %Text;         #REQUIRED -- short description --
  longdesc    %URI;          #IMPLIED  -- link to long description
                                          (complements alt) --
  name        CDATA          #IMPLIED  -- name of image for scripting --
  height      %Length;       #IMPLIED  -- override height --
  width       %Length;       #IMPLIED  -- override width --
  usemap      %URI;          #IMPLIED  -- use client-side image map --
  ismap       (ismap)        #IMPLIED  -- use server-side image map --
  >
```

We'd better use something else if we want to do this.

Comment: Transformation is already taking place, so `<img align="right" src="...">` could become `<div style="float: right;"><img ... /></div>`, for example.