# Allow floating images in Stackexchange Questions and Answers

Tags: discussion, markdown

The Stack Exchange engine uses [Markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) for questions and answers. You are allowed to [intermix some **HTML** tags and **Markdown** tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135909/188615). But with these allowed tags it is not possible to float a text around a small image.

Floating text around small images works great on questions that have large blocks of text with small images scattered throughout.

It would be great, if you would allow the `align`-attribute in `img`-tags. or some other solution.

Maybe with a limitation in width and height of the image.

---

**Note:**
It already is possible to position small images inline.

Example: 100,00 [image: Bitcoin currency sign] (with the correct Bitcoin currency sign)

Comment: What would be a use-case where this would be required?

Comment: No repro on mobile (Chrome 28.0.1500.16, WebKit 536.26 [iOS 6.1.3]). The image is on the next line.

Comment: especially, when you have an image with little width but really high

Comment: I prefer it to be as basic as possible. That way it helps posts be more consistent. If we add too much creative control then each page will start to look completely different from all the rest

Comment: @Bart if you look at the bottom, it would be (in this case) to add the Bitcoin icon as a suffix. Personally, I would just use BIT$100.00.

Comment: @rubo77 yes. On my phone, it's on the next line. Should I show a screenshot?

Comment: @ColeJohnson So that is already possible. But do we really have that many very tall and narrow images that we require formatting like that? Anything that currently really is problematic?

Comment: @Bart none that I've seen.

Comment: And if you're going to use *semantic* images, please please please make sure that you fill in the alt text. Be kind to the blind. (But really, an *image* for a *currency symbol*? That's nonsense.)

Comment: @CodyGray: there is no unicode for the current Bitcoin symbol yet: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Bitcoin_symbol

Comment: You could also place several small images beside each other with float. Or an image on the left and the description on the right. I can imagine numerous occasions where floating is really helpful. **Floating text around small images works great on questions that have large blocks of text with small images scattered throughout.**