# Extend image formatting

Tags: feature-request, markdown, images

I've not found any way to center image for my post. And, good chances are - there's no way to do this. So may be we should have extended options for images?

- Text positioning
- Horizontal alignment (left/center/right)

Also, I didn't found any usage for "image description", only [as "no image" place](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post) for browsers where images are turned off / not supported. No other usages - but it is such a rare case when browser don't support images. So may be we'll use that for image title as it is? (that is - when mouse pointer is on the image, the description will pop-up as a hint).

Example - [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21110548/2637490) answer - there are many pictures there, I've entered proper description for each case (so it will be easy to realize what is image about, without scrolling to text above it) - so it would be great if that description will appear when mouse pointer is on the picture. It will also be great if pictures will be centered or the text of the post, which is related to picture, will be at the left/right side of it.

So may be such extension to image formatting should be added?

<sub>May be it's a duplicate, but I wasn't able to find exactly same question. If it is - then, please, correct me.</sub>

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25835/is-it-possible-to-horizontally-center-an-image-in-sofu <-- sure this isn't a dupe?

Comment: Image title is already supported and mentioned [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2133/whats-the-recommended-syntax-for-an-image-with-a-link/57567#57567). As for the other request of aligning, not sure how helpful this would be.

Comment: Text alignment will never happen. There's no reason you'd actually need that.

Comment: @Oded right, but not _exact_ dupe, I believe - that's a way to _do something_ with the problem, while I suggest - to add regular way to do formatting

Comment: @animuson Yeah, [even Joel](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99573/can-we-get-a-way-to-wrap-text-around-images) couldn't get that.

Comment: We are very wary of adding custom extensions to markdown. It is a spec and it aims at simplicity. Adding more cruft to it goes against its goals.

Comment: @TimStone yay. If __even Joel__ can't get that - then - really - no chances

Comment: @TimStone that was quite funny to see. CEO asks for something and being declined is a rare sight. :)

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is really necessary. We're not really focused on 'styling' the content - merely presenting it. We have enough problems with people getting `creative` with the *text* **formatting** <sup>options</sup> we have now; I shudder to think of what would be done with various image formatting options.

I think the best way to present informational images is as they are now: As a 'block' in the text, with maximum width set to the container's width (or close to it, anyway)

You are basically right about the image descriptions. They are there for proper usability. I suppose you could include an empty description, if you wanted.

---

Oh, I missed something! I do think it could be useful to add a `title` attribute to the `<img>` tag produced here, with the content being the description, also; as you note, that would cause the tooltip.

Comment: Fair point, but sometimes such editing (well, at least, horizontal positioning) may significant increase readability. I agree, it's quite rare, when many pictures are needed - but still such cases may exist

Comment: Not sure if this is pertinent, @AlmaDo but there is one trick I have used once or twice to help with clarity of images, particularly when they contain lots of 'white' space (where 'white' here is whatever the background color is)... enclose the image in a blockquote area. It doesn't align/format it, but it does help to differentiate the image from the text.

Comment: @AlmaDo I added agreement about the tooltips on the images, though!

Comment: Hm. That helps a little (I've edited and now it's much better). But really - it's about being "smarter" than system and overcome it's restrictions. I was asking about regular way to do that - but, it seems, I've got my answer in comments

Comment: Note - you can to hover over comments, exactly the same as those produced by the title attribute, by adding it in "quotes" after the URL. Oh, and my opinion is that it would be *brilliant* to center (and/or right align (left aligned by default)) images - otherwise I just chuck in loads on non-breaking spaces (`&nbsp;`) on the same line before the picture